# How can I make the Decimal class round down instead of to the nearest value?

Tags: python, decimal

I tried this code using [the `decimal` standard library module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(22)/Decimal(7)
Decimal('3.14286')
```

It appears to have rounded the value to the nearest representable one.

How can I make it truncate instead, to give a result of `3.14285`?

Comment: nothing is rounded in Decimal... its just the print ... you can do `"{0:0.6f}".format(Decimal(22)/Decimal(7))` at least as far as i understand without testing ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Comment: @JoranBeasley: you are absolutely wrong. Decimal *does* round (or truncate, depending on the behaviour you specify in the context). That's what the precision value is for. Try `'{:.50f}'.format(Decimal(22)/Decimal(7))` and see all those zeroes at the end.

Comment: ok thanks for correcting me :)  ... sorry for any confusion my comment may have caused

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like you specify precision using the Decimal context you can also specify rounding rules.

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 6 
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_FLOOR

print Decimal(22)/Decimal(7)
```

the result will be

```
3.14285
```

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context

Comment: Thank you very much! Never occured to me search for 'floor' haha!

Comment: If you only want to change the context for this part of code, a `with localcontext() as ctx: ctx.prec=6; ctx.rounding = ROUND_FLOOR; print Decimal(22)/Decimal(7)` could be helpful.